# Feathers-Objection $sort parent by child relation field

Tags: postgresql, feathersjs, objection.js

There is a products model that hasOne brand and hasMany attributes. I am trying to sort products by brand.name. `{{apiUrl}}/product?$eager=[brand, attributes]&$joinRelation=[brand]&$sort[brand.name]=-1`

This however resulted in `SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

So I tried `{{apiUrl}}/product?$joinEager=[brand, attributes]&$sort[brand.name]=-1` which works, but due to needing pagination the limit is applied to the hasMany relations.

How can I sort products by brand name while also including hasMany relations?